# C# : how to schedule a certain limit of restarts for my PC

Tags: c#, windows, operating-system

I have an application which uses the microsoft kinect device. The thing is that at certain moments, the device may not be functional, and I plan to restart my PC in order to try to reset the kinect status.

The thing is that I want to restart the PC for a limited number of times.

I am planning to check how many restarts were given to my PC by writing the date at which the PC was restarted in a file from my HDD, and check that file for future restarts.

Is there any other way of checking how many restarts were given to my PC before a given time?

Comment: I think you should write a counter to the Registry and then restart. That way when the counter gets to a certain number you can skip the restart. You will also want to write the time of the most recent restart so you can reset the counter if it hasnt been restarted recently.

Comment: You can write a simple application that updates a file(may be text) every time it is run. And this can be put in startup items to run automatically when the user logs on. Then you can check from the file about the number of restarts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look in the event log and count for the event.

If you look through I can see for example 6009 is the first event after a power up on my machine running windows 7, you then have a date stamp and when it started, you can then work from there.

Comment: for instanse like this System.Diagnostics.EventLog.GetEventLogs();